# iTunes can't download song purchased from old computer, on to new computer

Tags: itunes, music, itunes-store

I bought and downloaded a song in iTunes on a PC of mine. I never synced it to my iPhone. Well, I got a new computer, and no long have the old one. I think there might be a problem now.

Here is what happens when I click **Check For Available Downloads** in iTunes:
[image: All purchases have been downloaded for this account.]

And here is what happens when I click on buy, for the song in the iTunes Store:
[image: You have purchased this item before.]

Is this a case of a badly worded dialog? I've seen something like this before in the App Store when I needed to reinstall a paid app. In that case I "bought" the app again, the second time without being charged.

Comment: What country are you in and which iTunes store do you buy from?  In some countries (such as Australia) music cannot be re-downloaded.  Only apps and books can be re-downloaded.

Comment: This is happening in the Japanese store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the expected behaviour. Re-download of music is not supported.
You have a only a few options:

- Wait for iCloud to become available for Japan. Currently *Automatic Downloads* for Music is only available in the US. Once it is eneblaed internationally you can enable it as Hand-E-Food described in his answer.
- E-Mail Apple support and tell them you lost the music due to an hardware-crash or something similar. There are reports that Apple support allows re-downloads of your complete purchase history. But this is a one time offer and a courtesy of Apple.

Comment: Getting support went well. My "personal" rep added the song to my account, and upon checking for available downloads again, there it was.

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes 10.3.3 or later, select **Edit**, **Preferences**, **Store**.  Under **Automatic Downloads** you can select which categories to automatically download.  If **Music** isn't an option, then you'll have to transfer your library manually.  I suspect **Music** is only an option in the US.

See [iTues Store Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4539) for more information.

Comment: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. Wow, besides specifically saying that you can download previously purchased music, reading on into the footnotes, it says it's only supported in the US. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519?viewlocale=ja_JP#1